# (Co)kriging / co-located kriging with heterogenous measurement errors

Tags: r, spatial, interpolation, kriging

I have a large set of polygons on a map, some of which contain data on 2 count variables, say ($z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$) that are correlated. In fact, $z_{2}$ most likely causes $z_{1}$ without the possibility of reverse causation. I need to interpolate $z_{1}$ to polygons with missing values, possibly with the help of $z_{2}$ within a co-kriging/co-located kriging setting. There is a couple of important aspects to the data:

1. Both $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ oberved data measurements have standard errors that are independent of each other.
2. There are also 4 types of polygons in my set, such that some have data on both $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$, some have
   one or the other, and some have neither.

Questions:

1. How can I incorporate the measurement error from the input data to
   interpolate $z_{1}$, preferably with the help of $z_{2}$?
2. Subsequently, is there a trade-off in terms of the accuracy of the
   resultant values to using co-kriging to interpolate $z_{1}$ to
   polygons that contain neither $z_{1}$ nor $z_{2}$?

Any advice, applied resources, code samples, or papers would be welcome.

I am aware of the issues surrounding Area-to-Area and Area-to-Point kriging, so let's assume these considerations are not part of this question. In full disclosure, I am piggybacking off [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162052/kriging-with-individual-errors) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273084/kriging-with-uncertain-observational-data) posts that provided some insight, but left me curious for more. Also, I am using `R`, so any advice on a package(s) that may be useful like `DiceKriging` is appreciated.

Comment: The techniques of [`geoRglm`](https://rdrr.io/cran/geoRglm/) are the appropriate ones, but I don't know whether the software has implemented cokriging.